# How to get refs object in vue after an aspx page is submitted

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am converting an ASPX page to vue. All the vue components are loaded properly and I am getting refs objects also

```
`<test-report ref="testReport" ></test-report>
<script>
method:{
 Loaded:{
    this.objResult = this.refs.testReport 
   }
},
```

`

But after the ASPX page is submitted I need to display some another data in vue component but the refs object is showing undefined. I need to call another function inside that object but it is showing undefined.

```
`<script>
method:{
 AfterLoaded:{
     this.objResult = this.refs.testReport  //showing undefined
   }
},
</script>`
```

Please help

Comment: can you share any info on how you managed to get vue.js components into aspx pages

Answer (score 0):

try using **this.$refs.nameOfRef** or **this.$refs.testReport** in your case

Comment: I have done that but I can't get the function called inside that vue component "testReport". It will only show HTML Elements